# Is there a c# compiler/runtime for js in the browser

Tags: .net-core, webassembly

basically dotnetfiddle as a js library such that I can do something like:

```js
dotnetfiddle.Run(`
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}`);
```

and it would run in the DotNet Dlls/runtimes

Comment: Blazor WASM, I guess...

Comment: I did find someone that got pretty far with it: https://github.com/LostBeard/BlazorWASMScriptLoader/tree/main/BlazorWASMScriptLoader/Services
but not quite yet